# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WebActivator'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, webactivator

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.
My Steps
-Create a New ASP .NET MVC 4 application
-choose basic template
-go to Package Manager Console
-try to install WebActivator

```
PM> Install-Package WebActivator
```

and i get the following error
[image]

How i can resolve this and install WebActivator package?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So easy

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivator

Need point version of webActivator!!!

```
PM> Install-Package WebActivator -Version 1.5.3
```

Comment: or PM> Install-Package WebActivatorEx

Answer (score 77):

In my case, I could not install any package and got a similar error. The issue was solved as I unchecked the "Microsoft and .NET" under "Machine-wide package source":

[image]

I hope this can be help someone.

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful.  I wish I understood the mechanics of why this caused a problem.

Comment: I had to uncheck a second source under "Available package sources". It resolved and installed when nuget.org was the only source checked.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Fayssal. I love you.

Comment: I had other different entries in this list, I had to uncheck all of them to make it work. I didn't try to install webactivator but Aws Dynamodb.

Answer (score 16):

I got a similar problem with another package in Visual Studio 2013, I cleared the NuGet package cache with the option "Clear Package Cache" and it works now.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change source according to [visual studio version](https://www.nuget.org/)

```
NuGet feed v3 (VS 2015 / NuGet v3.x): https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
NuGet feed v2 (VS 2013 and earlier / NuGet 2.x): https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself.  The reference to WebActivatorEx didn't work.  You'll have to do it manually.  The file is in the packages directory.