# Error in installing spark view engine

Tags: .net, nuget, spark-view-engine

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059464/install-package-unable-to-find-package-webactivator).
I tried that solution of the accepted answer. No luck for me.

I tried by running this command through Package manager console

> Install-Package Spark.Web.Mvc4

It gives the following error

> PM> Install-Package Spark.Web.Mvc4 Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Spark (≥ 1.8.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivator (≥
>   2.0.6)'. Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'WebActivator (≥ 2.0.6)'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Spark.Web.Mvc4
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I tried installing web activator separately from this link
[here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/2.0.2),

That got installed successfully. Still when i try Spark it says same error.

Please help me in fixing this..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in NuGet package version v1.8.1.0 - it was previously using the wrong WebActivator package accidentally.