# Nuget Cannot find most packages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've installed Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015, yet when i try to install most packages I am met with the following error.  Any ideas what this issue is would be greatly appreciated...

[image: error]

Comment: if not a problem with internet then maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059464/install-package-unable-to-find-package-webactivator) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464558/nuget-fails-to-find-existing-package) could help.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your package source, in the drop down at the top left of the Package Manager Console, is currently set to Microsoft and .NET. If you change it to be **nuget.org** then it should work.

The [Microsoft and .NET package source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/nugetpackages.aspx) contains the NuGet packages that Microsoft supports which is subset of the packages available from nuget.org.

Comment: Wow silly me! Seems like the package source for some reason resets to microsoft and .Net when i shut all instances of visual studio 2015 and later reload a project.  Cheers!

Comment: +1. Had the same issue with NuGet Package Manager GUI, though Console worked. Surprisingly, I just did not have an appropriate package source configured at all. I have no idea where it should have come from and how it has disappeared. Before this post, I thought that "Microsoft and .NET" is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to the Tools -> Options menu, expand NuGet Package Manager, and then click on Package Sources. Ensure "Microsoft and .NET" is checked in the Machine-wide Package list.

When you next start the Package Manager make sure the Package Source dropdown at the top-right has a value selected.